# ¿Como evitar dos usuarios repitan un mismo valor en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

session_start (); 

include 'dbh.inc.php';
include 'login.inc.php'; 

$nuevonick = $_POST['nuevonick'];
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if ( isset($_POST['btnactualizar']) ) 

{


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_nick = '$nuevonick "; $result =         mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

            if (!$resultcheck > 0) { header("Location: ../index.php?    cambio=invalido"); 
                                exit(); /* por si algo pasa*/}

                else
                {

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_nick = '$nuevonick' WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
                mysqli_query ($conn, $sql); 
                $_SESSION['nick'] = $nuevonick; 
                header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");                            
                exit ();
                }



}

else

{
echo 'error';
}
```

---

Hasta hace unos momentos cuando hice este código funcionaba sin problemas, ahora sin importar que, permite actualizar al usuario a un nick que ya existe en la base de datos... =S no entiendo

Comment: hiciste un debug o algo que pueda ayudar a saber que pasa?

Comment: También puedes agregar el atributo unique al campo de la tabla en la base de datos.
Si trata de registrar un el mismo valor, retorna un error.

Comment: Gracias Alonso, me sirvió, no conocía que podías hacer eso.